# Taylor series of $f(x)=\frac{1}{4+x^2}$, with $f:D\to\mathbb{R}, D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ at $x^*=0$.

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

> Taylor series of $f(x)=\frac{1}{4+x^2}$, with $f:D\to\mathbb{R}, D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ at $x^*=0$ and determining the radius of convergence of the series.

I've calculated the first 3 derivatives in order to figure out the $n$-th derivative. Unfortunately I couldn't really find a pattern. In order to create the series I will need the $n$-th derivative, that's why I'm stuck here. Can you help me with finding the $n$-th derivative?

$\begin{align}
f(x)'=&-\frac{2x}{(4+x^2)^2}\\
f(x)''=&\frac{6x^2-8}{(x^2+4)^3}=\dfrac{2\left(\color{limegreen}{3x^2-4}\right)}{\left(x^2+4\right)^3}\\
f(x)'''=&-\frac{24x(\color{blue}{x^2-4})}{(x^2+4)^4}=\dfrac{12x}{\left(x^2+4\right)^3}-\dfrac{12x\left(\color{limegreen}{3x^2-4}\right)}{\left(x^2+4\right)^4}\\
f(x)^{(4)}=&\frac{24\left(\color{red}{5x^4-40x^2+16}\right)}{\left(x^2+4\right)^5}=-\frac{48x^2}{\left(x^2+4\right)^4}-\frac{24\left(\color{blue}{x^2-4}\right)}{\left(x^2+4\right)^4}+\frac{192x^2\left(x^2-4\right)}{\left(x^2+4\right)^5}\\
f(x)^{(5)}=&-\frac{240x\left(3x^4-40x^2+48\right)}{\left(x^2+4\right)^6}=\frac{24\left(20x^3-80x\right)}{\left(x^2+4\right)^5}-\frac{240x\left(\color{red}{5x^4-40x^2+16}\right)}{\left(x^2+4\right)^6}
\end{align}$

I can see some sort of pattern highlighted in different colors but I'm not sure how I could express it exactly.

It should look similar to this:

$$f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n\cdot \frac{?}{(4+x^2)^n}$$

Comment: Do you see a pattern in the derivatives evaluated at $0$?

Comment: This series is most easily deduced from the *geometric series*. Why make things harder than they really are?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh, yeah that would be easier. I think it's $f^n(x)=(-1)^n\cdot \frac{n!\cdot 2^n}{(x^2+4)^{n+1}}$?

Comment: @Bernard can you please explain a little further?

Comment: Write your function as $\frac14\frac1{1+\bigl(\frac x2)^2}$, set $u=\bigl(\frac x2\bigr)^2$ and expand $\frac 1{1+u}$.

Comment: The $n^{th}$ derivative is $0$ at $0$ when $n$ is odd; it's an even function

Comment: Yeah, sry forgot to write that down.

Comment: Don't you know the expansion of $\frac1{1+u}$? It is the alternating geometric series.

Comment: No, I didn't knew that.

Comment: I just searched it on the internet. You mean the fact, that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-x)^k=\frac{1}{1+x}$ ?

Comment: Yes, I meant that: $\;\dfrac1{1+u}=\dfrac1{1-(-u)}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^ku^k$, it's as simple as that

Comment: Sry, I probably encountered this series somewhere, sometime ago. Thank you for refreshing my mind.

Comment: You're welcome! :) B.t.w. it is the basis fo the expansion of $\arctan x$